# What characters in key_name?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I wonder what you can use as a key_name?
I do a lot of queries on non-ascii unicode characters, I wonder if I can use these as key names to speed up the queries.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [the documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keysandentitygroups.html), key_name is a unicode string, though plain `str` values get converted as ASCII -- so you'll want to make sure you're actually providing a true unicode string (I *strongly* suggest reading the *entire* Python [Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html)).

Comment: I can use non latin characters, but I have problems using get_by_key_name() to get long keys (several characters)

Comment: @user: Not sure why that would be. Key length limits are something like 500 bytes, and even worst-case UTF-8 encoded strings could fit dozens of characters in there. Do you have an extremely long path, perchance?

Comment: No long path.
I think it is an encoding problem.
I don't know where though, I made sure to use unicode strings.
It seems I can create keys, but I can get them only if they are 1 character long.